# Integrating Foursquare to my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to integrate Foursquare to my iPhone app.

I need to do the following;

1.) Find shops/store nearby to me
2.) Check-in via my application

I need to know if these are possible, and would appreciate if someone could help me to find a good tutorial or some sample code to start off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's site for a start:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial

Comment: I get this error, when i try to run the application `Storyboards are unavailable on iOS 4.3 and prior.` any clue ?

Comment: The tutorial and sample code were written for iOS 5 and newer. You would need to install a newer version of XCode to run the project directly. If you can't, the article should at least point you in the direction of what you need to do to call Foursquare's API's.